# Chrome extension: appending DIV to BODY element within content script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Within me Google Chrome extension I would like to inject some HTML code into website by appending a DIV to the BODY element. My current test content script for this looks as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'blue'); // just for testing
  $('body').append("<div>hello world</div>");
};
```

The background color does change to blue. However, appending the DIV seems not. At least I cannot find anything on the page or in the page source code. What am I missing here?

Comment: This works fine here, but if you are putting this code into the Chrome DevTools Console, you should probably don't use `window.load`, since the event has already been fired it won't be executed again.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to add **window.onload** because content scripts load when the page is already loaded, [see this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). remember to add permissions in manifist correctly:

```
"permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["js/contentscript.js"]
  }
]
```

I assumed that your content script will load in all tabs and it loades the content script from js folder.